# Lightning - Server Response Error

Tags: lightning

I am trying to create a simple book entry form as a lightning component.

Book__c is a custom object with just two fields (Book_Name__c & Book_Author__c)

**Component markup**

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:attribute name="book" type="Book__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Book__c','Book_Name__c':'','Book_Author__c':''}"/>

    <div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">
        <header class="slds-card__header">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Create a New Book</h3>
        </header>


    </div>

    <form class="slds-form--stacked">

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookName" label="Book Name:" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Name__c}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookAuthor" label="Book Author:" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Author__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:button label="Add New Book" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.AddNewBookHandler}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
    AddNewBookHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newBook = component.get("v.book");
        var action=component.get("c.saveBook");
        action.setParams({"book":newBook});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
           var state = response.getState();

            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
            {
                alert("Book Saved Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                alert("Book Not Saved Successfully");
                console.log("Response = "+response);
                console.log("Response State ="+response.getState());
                console.log("Response Return Value = "+response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex controller**

```
public class BookController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveBook(Book__c b)
    {
        Book__c inputBook = new Book__c();
        inputBook.Book_Author__c = b.Book_Author__c;
        inputBook.Book_Name__c = b.Book_Name__c;
        insert inputBook;
        return 'test';
    }

}
```

**Application markup**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:CreateBookComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

I enter the book name and book author and when I click on the button the record does not get saved.

I added few console.logs to determine what could be the reason and I am unable to figure it out further as the response object is opaque with only few info available.

**Console logs screenshot**

[image]

Can someone help as to why the response is throwing an error ?

FYI...The same apex controller works fine in anonymous execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mistake is at   <s>action.setParams({"book":newBook});</s>  In your apex you referncing as
`public static String saveBook(Book__c b)` that is you refered as `Book__c b`

you need to set same referenced name in component controller to set

```
action.setParams({"b":newBook});
```